# Fail to install my NetBeans plugin

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

Playing around with creating a NetBeans plugin but I am making very little progress since the process of installing the module fails. What I am doing is right-clicking on the and choosing the 'Install/Reload in Development IDE' option and it fails with the following exception:

```
Enabling StandardModule:org.willcodejavaforfood.com jarFile: /Users/Erik/NetBeansProjects/module2/build/cluster/modules/org-willcodejavaforfood-com.jar...
java.io.IOException: Cannot enable StandardModule:org.willcodejavaforfood jarFile: /Users/Erik/NetBeansProjects/module2/build/cluster/modules/org-willcodejavaforfood.jar; problems: [Java > 1.6]
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.deployTestModule(ModuleSystem.java:358)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.TestModuleDeployer.deployTestModule(TestModuleDeployer.java:68)
        at org.netbeans.modules.apisupport.ant.InstallModuleTask.execute(InstallModuleTask.java:77)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:273)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:499)
        at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:151)
```

Using NetBeans 6.5 and running Java 1.6 on Mac OS X 10.5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apperently this is a NetBeans issue for Mac OS X...

[Answer from netbeans forums](http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=26822#26822)

Answer (score 0):

If you make a new NetBeans module project and simply run that does it work?  (trying to narrow the issue down, and eliminating anything but the absolute basics is a good place to start)

Comment: yes if I just run it, a new instance of netbeans is started with the module installed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your target platform is set to JDK 5 but your module is built against JDK 6.